# IClaimsTransformation claims not sticking

Tags: claims-based-identity, claims

I've followed the tutorial from Microsoft on .NET Core claims (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0#extend-or-add-custom-claims-using-iclaimstransformation)

The line if (!principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == claimType)) is always true - i.e. the claim never exists in the ClaimsPrinciple after refreshing the page.

Any reason why it wouldn't stick? I have the class inherited from IClaimsTransformation and have hooked it up in program.cs

Answer (score 2):

I have checked into this using .NET 6, Microsoft.Identity.Web, and Blazor Server.

The documentation says "This method *might* get called multiple times."

For me, the IClaimsTransformation is called each time. The *might* never happens.

After debugging, it seems the Microsoft.Identity.Web is providing the initial claims. The initial claims are passed to IClaimsTransformation and then my custom claims are added as a second Identity Principal which is this section of code:

```
principal.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);
```

My custom claims are never added in duplicate and the IClaimsTransformation method fires multiple times for each page/component load.

Long story short, I think the custom claims are cleared and re-added each time IClaimsTransformation is run.

At first I was worried about performance because I was loading data from a database to generate the custom claims. So...I timed it and reading the database only required 44ms to 54ms - in other words negligible even at scale. Another benefit, is that as soon as the database is updated the claims are almost immediately reflected to the end user.

To verify yourself, you can add your custom claims using IClaimsTransformation and then setup a page to iterate through all the claims. Your custom claims should be there so long as you added the service during start-up:

```
services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, UserClaimsTransformation>();
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that this should be added as a transient instead of scoped?   I always get confused when to use which.

Comment: The Microsoft github page for Authentication Claims shows transient so I went with it! And, maybe the only time I have used transient! Transient will rebuild the values each time the service is called. Scoped may not. Here is the page that shows Transient: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/security/authentication/claims.md and here is a nice explanation of Dependency Injection lifetimes: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/differences-between-scoped-transient-and-singleton-service/